# Black screen after switching from windows to ubuntu budgie

Tags: boot, usb, windows, ubuntu-budgie

I downloaded ubuntu budgie on usb, then installed ubuntu budgie and deleted windows from my laptop, afterwards it was loading and something like "plug off mediator and press enter" popped out so I plugged off usb and pressed enter. Then screen turned black, I was waiting for about 15 minutes, tried to turn off and turn on but it still is completely black. Is everything really bad or it is some minor problem? I mean ubuntu was completly installed so it shouldn't be so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something was wrong with my laptop, I just had to unplug charger and everything started to work properly.